# Collect output of Roots[] into a list

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

If I do `Roots[a x^2 + b  x + c == 0, x]`, the output is

`x == (-b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a) || 
 x == (-b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)`

How do I collect the output of `Roots` into a list like so `{(-b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a), (-b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)}` so that I can plot it?

Comment: What do you want to plot[] exactly?  ... there could be better ways ...

Comment: i want to plot the output of roots[]. roots[] typically spits out something like x==a||x==b||x==c, which is not plottable. sjoerd's answer fixes that.

Comment: A plot is typically: 1) a function of variables or 2) a list of points. What are you trying to plot? What function? What variables? Or what points?

Comment: It's clear from my question that the list of points that I want to plot are the roots of a function that is returned by Roots[f[x],x].

Comment: No, it isn't. A root is a scalar, and it's very difficult to imagine the need to represent only two points on a straight line. Only a homework may ask for that. But be my guess and do it if you want. Sorry for asking.

Comment: A single root is a scalar; a set of roots is a list. The quadratic function was just a quick example. My function is a order 1000 polynomial, with 1000 roots, and no particular structure to it. The exact function is irrelevant to the question, and a homework question would've just listed the question and asked for help to solve. I appreciate your help, but my sole aim was in knowing how to get rid of the `x==` in the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x /. {ToRules[Roots[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x]]} // Flatten

==> {(-b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a), (-b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)}
```

Answer (score 7):

An alternative (obvious?} method:

```
List @@ Roots[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x][[All, 2]]
```

giving

[image]

Comment: Definitely not obvious.